# Traverse directory tree in node.js using RxJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to traverse directory tree using RxJs and node.js.

I came up with working solution:

```
const filesInDir = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(fs.readdir)
const statFile = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(fs.stat)

const listFiles = (prefix, dir = '') => {
    const file$ = filesInDir(`${prefix}/${dir}`)
        .flatMap(file => file)
        .filter(file => !file.startsWith('.'))
    const isDir$ = file$
        .map(file => statFile(`${prefix}/${dir}/${file}`))
        .flatMap(file => file)
        .map(file => file.isDirectory())
    return file$
        .zip(isDir$, (file, isDir) => {return {file, isDir}})
        .map(f => {
            if (f.isDir) {
                return listFiles(prefix, `${dir}/${f.file}`)
            }
            return Rx.Observable.return(`${dir}/${f.file}`)
        })
        .flatMap(file => file)
}

listFiles('public')
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(list => {
        console.log(list)
    })
```

Questions:

1. Is there more efficient/concise way to `.map` using asynchronous operation?
2. Same question for the `.zip` part

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question.

I think you can do a few things to optimise this query.

Firstly we can change the `map` opeartors followed by `.flatMap(file => file)` to just a single flatMap. Tiny improvement, but will run less code.

```
const file$ = filesInDir(`${prefix}/${dir}`)
    .flatMap(file => file)
    .filter(file => !file.startsWith('.'))
const isDir$ = file$
    .flatMap(file => statFile(`${prefix}/${dir}/${file}`))
    .map(file => file.isDirectory())
return file$
    .zip(isDir$, (file, isDir) => {return {file, isDir}})
    .flatMap(f => {
        if (f.isDir) {
            return listFiles(prefix, `${dir}/${f.file}`)
        }
        return Rx.Observable.return(`${dir}/${f.file}`)
    })
```

The main improvement is where I believe you are actually hitting the File System twice. 
The `filesInDir` observable sequence is not a hot/cached sequence.
If it was, the recursive walking of the directory tree wouldn't work.
With that in mind, you are calling it once to get all the files, and then you are calling it again to do the `isDirectory` check.
This introduces both a potential performance cost, and a bug.
You are making the assumption that when you hit the disk that the sequence of files that are returned will always be in the same order.
Even if we ignore for a second, that disk is mutable and it *could* change under you.
You can be guaranteed that in an async world that the sequences will be returned in the same order. 
On my machine (Windows 10) the sequence is mostly returned in the same order.
However with a deep enough tree (e.g. from _C:_) I hit a mismatch every-time.

Anyway, the performance fix is also the bug fix.
Instead of re-reading from the file system every time, we can do it once.
Moving the `statFile()` call into a `flatMap` that also maps the result with the closure of the file passed to `statFile`

```
const listFiles = (prefix, dir) => {
    return file$ = filesInDir(`${prefix}/${dir}`)
        .flatMap(file => file)
        .filter(file => !file.startsWith('.'))
        .flatMap(file => statFile(`${prefix}/${dir}/${file}`)
                    .map( sf => {return {file, isDir: sf.isDirectory()}}) )
        .flatMap(f => {
            if (f.isDir) {
                return listFiles(prefix, `${dir}/${f.file}`)
            }
            return Rx.Observable.return(`${dir}/${f.file}`)
        })
}
```

This also has the benefit of removing the `Zip` clause because we are no longer trying to work with two sequences.